# How to start a terminal window in the center of the screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

It's kind of annoying how some Ubuntu (GNOME, X Window System) programs start at the top left of my screen. Is there a way to make the program start in the center of the screen.

(Yeah I know it's a pretty trivial question but it is annoying ;-)

Comment: Which window manager/desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use x's geometry to set this.

depending on your x version it can vary.

the man page and it should explain the geometry options

xterm 80x24+nxn or similar.

Comment: What does nxn do?

Comment: n would represent the number you want to set.

Comment: Why is it so hard to find information about geometry using a man page?

Comment: 'man X', search for "GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS".

Comment: It says 'No manual entry for X.
See man 7 undocumented for help when manual pages are not available'.

Comment: **apt-get install xorg-docs-core** 

(at least, that's the debian package name.  the ubuntu packaged will probably have the same name...or similar)

Answer (score 6):

In gnome-terminal (ubuntu) the geometry specification is slightly different:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=114x32+0+0
```

As ever the man pages are your friend:

```
man gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 5):

The question title is only about the Terminal, however, it seems the body is more general about "programs start at the top left of [… the] screen".

So, since GNOME v3.30 there is a visible option in [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks), which makes it easy to enable it for all windows:

[image: GNOME Tweaks with Windows->"Center New Windows" highlighted]

Just select "Center New Windows" under "Windows".

Comment: BTW, in contrast to what i said, (that it's the default in Ubuntu now) this topic is not dead and still in discussion in [Fedora](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/should-gnome-center-new-windows-by-default-or-not/1413?u=rugk) & [Ubuntu](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/center-windows-by-default/10262?u=rugk).

Answer (score 1):

most (probably all) window managers have configuration options that you can tweak to set where new windows are opened.

some examples:

openbox has a check-box "Center new windows when they are placed".  that causes all new windows(*) to open in the centre of the screen.

sawfish is very flexible and programmable - you can set rules so that windows matching certain criteria are always centered, always opened in desktop 2, have a different frame style, and so.

i can't remember exactly what metacity is capable of...haven't used it for ages.  i think it can centre windows by default.

(*) by default, that is.  if they're opened with a specific geometry then that overrides the default.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the centering problem (in X) either, so I just did some rough math on my screen dimensions to determine a close centerpoint.  I needed this for my terminal window, similar to Ken above.

Here is what i have my terminal icon mapped to, which is close to center on my 1900x1200 resolution:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=90x20+400+300
```

(That's   width(columns) x hight(rows) + xoffset + y offset

To add to this, I have an alias in my .bashrc which I use when I need to open 4 terminals fast.  The below will open 4 terminals, each pinned to the 4 corners, and 100 columns by 23 rows.  Note that I go out of order in the calls so that the last line executed (the last terminal opened) is the upper left one, allowing me to start there.

```
# Open 4 terminal windows on the corners.  Upper rt, low left, low right, upper left
alias bam="     gnome-terminal --geometry=100x23-700+0; 
                gnome-terminal --geometry=100x23+0-400; 
                gnome-terminal --geometry=100x23-700-400;
                gnome-terminal --geometry=100x23+0+0;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open all windows in  the center by configuring gnome:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true
```